# Try to upload files to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to upload some file to the server using ASP.NET MVC.

The JS code that I write in my index in this:

```
@section Scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dropArea').filedrop({
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles")',
            allowedfiletypes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'],
            allowedfileextensions: ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'],
            paramname: 'files',
            maxfiles: 5,
            maxfilesize: 5, 
            dragOver: function () {
                $('#dropArea').addClass('active-drop');
            },
            dragLeave: function () {
                $('#dropArea').removeClass('active-drop');
            },
            drop: function () {
                $('#dropArea').removeClass('active-drop');
            },
            afterAll: function (e) {
                $('#dropArea').html('file(s) uploaded successfully');
            },
            uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
                $('#uploadList').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + file.name + '</li>');
            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

The method from my controller is this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string filePath = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), filePath));               
        }

        return Json("file uploaded successfully");
}
```

When I try to upload some file I get this error:

[image]

Please tell me what should I add to my code from this to work.

Comment: Why don't you put a debug on your controller and check what is causing the exception? Or is it not hitting your breakpoint?

Comment: I try this and the files parameter is null. Now I try to debug in chrome console. From some reason the file is not coming on the server

Comment: It's exception on server side. Please put debug to check what is causing the exception

Comment: Please try this on your server side: var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                var files = httpRequest.Files; Then loop over files.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Your original code works when you are doing plain mvc style file uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `HttpPostedFileBase[]` instead of `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string filePath = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), filePath));
    }

    return Json("file uploaded successfully");
}
```